# Why Android EditText have to click the second time to trigger the event?

Tags: android

The xml file:

```
<EditText
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_lock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/et_pwd"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_closeeye_32"
        style="@style/editText_base"
        android:hint="@string/pwd_input"/>
```

Outside is LinearLayout

The code:

```
private boolean isTouch = false;
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            Drawable drawableRight = etPwd.getCompoundDrawables()[2];

            if(drawableRight == null && event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                return false;
            }
            if (event.getX() > etPwd.getWidth()
                    - etPwd.getPaddingRight()
                    - drawableRight.getIntrinsicWidth()){
                Drawable drawableLeft = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_lock);
                drawableLeft.setBounds(0, 0, drawableLeft.getMinimumWidth(), drawableLeft.getMinimumHeight());
                if (isTouch) {
                    etPwd.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                    Drawable drawableOpenEye = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_openeye_32);
                    drawableOpenEye.setBounds(0, 0, drawableOpenEye.getMinimumWidth(), drawableOpenEye.getMinimumHeight());
                    etPwd.setCompoundDrawables(drawableLeft, null, drawableOpenEye, null);
                } else {
                    etPwd.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                    Drawable drawableCloseEye = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_closeeye_32);
                    drawableCloseEye.setBounds(0, 0, drawableCloseEye.getMinimumWidth(), drawableCloseEye.getMinimumHeight());
                    etPwd.setCompoundDrawables(drawableLeft, null, drawableCloseEye, null);
                }
                isTouch = !isTouch;
                etPwd.setSelection(etPwd.getText().toString().length());
            }

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :

            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

[Now! Did not respond for the first time , Click the second time to show the icon open , to show / hide the password.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DonFs.png)

And i`ve already implements View.OnTouchListener , find the relevant controls to do the click event . Help me , thanks!

Comment: I think because the first click/touch you do to it would make the view focused, then the next click/touch would be the click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either change

```
private boolean isTouch = false;
```

to true.

```
private boolean isTouch = true;
```

Or you need to switch the blocks inside the `if` statement around.

The reason for this is because the first time it goes through the codeblock, isTouch is false, and it sets the transformation to password - which it's already in! Now isTouch is set to true, and the second time it goes through the expected code block to show the password.

Comment: oh , i am stupid , Now understanding! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_username"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <com.mycalculator.utils.CustomEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_pwd"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_show_pwd"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="@string/Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_show_pwd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_closeeye_32" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="6dp" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="90" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/Gray" />

</shape>
```

JAVA:

```
EditText et_pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pwd);
ImageView iv_show_pwd = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_show_pwd);


iv_show_pwd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (et_pwd.getTransformationMethod() == PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()) {
            et_pwd.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            iv_show_pwd.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_visible);
        } else {
            et_pwd.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            iv_show_pwd.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_invisible);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: so great! Compared to , simple and fast !